# How many arguments can be generated and why are they generated?

Tags: c, program-entry-point

I am using this code...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    int i =0;
    if (argc == 1){
        printf("You have entered 1 argument and you suck \n");
    }
    else if (argc > 1 && argc<4){
        for (i=0;i<4;i++){
            printf("you have entered the following args %d.%s \n",(i),argv[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("You have entered more than four arguments and you suck.\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If i change the for loop from `for (i=0;i<4;i++)` to `for (i=0;i<7;i++)`, I get this output:

```
cam@cam:~/Desktop/D/c/c-code$ ./ex12 hi there 
you have entered the following args 0../ex12 
you have entered the following args 1.hi 
you have entered the following args 2.there 
you have entered the following args 3.(null) 
you have entered the following args 4.XDG_VTNR=7 
you have entered the following args 5.LC_PAPER=en_IN.UTF-8 
you have entered the following args 6.ORBIT_SOCKETDIR=/tmp/orbit-cam
```

Why no error? Why are these variable which are related to my OS being generated?

Comment: My question was why Environmental variables??
I know the index is out of range.I purposefully changed it to see what happens

Comment: Any thing can happen. The code *can* print your environment variables,*can* format the hard disk, *can* make unicorns dance in front of your monitor etc etc. The consequences of Undefined Behavior are undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normal memory layout for a program on Unix systems is that the array of pointers to the program arguments is immediately followed by the array of pointers to the environment variables.

What you are doing is stepping beyond the array of argument pointers (note that there is a null pointer at `argv[argc]`) and into the array of environment pointers, which is also terminated by a null pointer.

#### Undefined behaviour

Because you are stepping beyond the end of the `argv` array, you are invoking **undefined behaviour**.  This is dangerous: anything could happen.  Sometimes, though, the result is benign — ***BUT*** you can never rely on that.

With the obligatory disclaimers out of the way,
you could get a complete dump of your environment with code like the following.  However, you ***must*** understand that the C standard does not guarantee anything about the behaviour after the clearly marked lines (and neither does POSIX).

The extra `envp` argument to `main()` is noted in Annex J.5.1 of the C Standard as a common extension — one that is supported by Microsoft Windows and by Unix systems.

> #### J.5.1 Environment arguments
>
> In a hosted environment, the `main` function receives a third argument, `char *envp[]`,
>   that points to a null-terminated array of pointers to `char`, each of which points to a string
>   that provides information about the environment for this execution of the program
>   (5.1.2.2.1).

This is not mandated by the standard; it is recognized by the standard as commonly available.  On POSIX systems, you can also get the environment variables via the global variable `char **environ`.  And, if you manipulate the environment with `setenv()` or `putenv()`, there is no guarantee that the value stored in `environ` remains the same as the value stored in `envp` passed to `main()`.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)
{
    int i;
    printf("Argc: %d\n", argc);
    for (i = 0; i < argc; i++)
        printf("Arg[%d]: <<%s>>\n", i, argv[i]);
    assert(argv[argc] == 0);
    assert(argv[i] == 0);

   /* Print the environment cleanly on most systems */
    char **ep;
    for (ep = envp; *ep != 0; ep++)
        printf("Env[%d]: <<%s>>\n", (int)(ep - envp), *ep);
    printf("Number of environment variables: %d\n", (int)(ep -envp));

    /* From here on, neither the C standard nor POSIX guarantees anything */
    /* In practice, it works on Unix systems; I don't know about Windows */
    assert(&argv[argc+1] == envp);
    for (i++; argv[i] != 0; i++)
        printf("Env[%d]: <<%s>>\n", i - argc - 1, argv[i]);
    printf("Number of environment variables: %d\n", i - argc - 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that even though Windows supports the third argument to `main()`, there's no guarantee that the memory it points at is immediately after the memory pointed at by `argv` (though it would not be surprising to find that it is the same layout as on Unix).  Technically, there's no guarantee on Unix that the `envp` array is immediately after the `argv` array; however, I've never come across a system where it isn't.

The `env` program allows you to set the environment for a command which it runs, and the `-i` option ignores any inherited environment.  That allows me to run the code above (compiled into a program `ev2`) like this:

```
$ env -i HOME=/home/elephant PATH=/home/elephant/bin:/bin:/usr/bin TZ=US/Pacific \
>     ./ev2 hello world
Argc: 3
Arg[0]: <<./ev2>>
Arg[1]: <<hello>>
Arg[2]: <<world>>
Env[0]: <<HOME=/home/elephant>>
Env[1]: <<PATH=/home/elephant/bin:/bin:/usr/bin>>
Env[2]: <<TZ=US/Pacific>>
Number of environment variables: 3
Env[0]: <<HOME=/home/elephant>>
Env[1]: <<PATH=/home/elephant/bin:/bin:/usr/bin>>
Env[2]: <<TZ=US/Pacific>>
Number of environment variables: 3
$
```

Answer (score 5):

Accessing an array out of bounds results in undefined behaviour. The consequences of undefined behaviour are *undefined*. Purely by coincidence you happen to be reading some environment variables. On other systems, or in other examples of this kind of behaviour, you might end up coincidentally reading some other piece of information (see *heartbleed* for a notable example) or coincidentally causing segfaults (crashes)... All of these outcomes are purely coincidental, however, and not to be relied upon.

Answer (score 3):

No extra arguments are "generated". Rather, since C does not have bounds checking (unlike some other languages), you accessed memory outside the array bounds, which happen to be the environment variables.

Comment: @Ajay , The code invokes Undefined Behavior and anything can happen.